# writing function , giving input and printing them with a condition

Tags: function, if-statement, input, printing, python-3.7

I want to write a function, which will accept parameter and it will print with a condition (It's output will depend on the input). My program is giving key error. I am looking for an output like:

This number is less than 0 and it's spelling is one hundred

thirteen

and my code is:

```
def word(num):
   d1= {0:'Zero',1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three',4:'Four',5:'Five',6:'Six',7:'Seven',8:'Eight',9:'Nine',10:'Ten',11:'Eleven',12:'Twelve',13:'Thirteen',14:'Fourteen',15:'Fifteen',16:'Sixteen',17:'Seventeen',18:'Eighteen',19:'Ninteen',20:'Twenty',30:'Thirty',40:'Fourty',50:'Fifty',60:'Sixty',70:'Seventy',80:'Eighty',90:'Ninty'}

   if (num<20):
      return d1[num]
   if (num<100):
      if num % 10 == 0:
         return d1[num]  
      else:
         return d1[num // 10 * 10] + ' ' + d1[num % 10]
   if (num < 0):
      return "This number is less than 0 and it's spelling is" + word(num)

print (word(- 100))
print (word(13))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have your wide condition before narrow condition.

In your code, you have 3 `if` conditions, `num < 20`, `num < 100`, `num < 0`, which **actually** is `0 <= num < 20`, `20 <= num < 100`, `num < 0`. The **last** condition is the widest, but you move it incorrectly at the bottom.

Sort your condition train into the order `num < 0`, `num < 20`, `num < 100` may fix this issue.

**Update:** You can't use `word[num]` in your `num < 0` block. I can't understand what "is one hundred" in your expected output. Is it a hardcoded text? Then hardcode it, for example:

```
def word(num): 
    d1= {0:'Zero',1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three',4:'Four',5:'Five',6:'Six',7:'Seven',8:'Eight',9:'Nine',10:'Ten',11:'Eleven',12:'Twelve',13:'Thirteen',14:'Fourteen',15:'Fifteen',16:'Sixteen',17:'Seventeen',18:'Eighteen',19:'Ninteen',20:'Twenty',30:'Thirty',40:'Fourty',50:'Fifty',60:'Sixty',70:'Seventy',80:'Eighty',90:'Ninty'}
    if num < 0: 
        return "This number is less than 0 and it's spelling is one hundred"
    if num < 20:
        return d1[num] 
    if num < 100:
        if num % 10 == 0:
            return d1[num] 
        else:
            return d1[num // 10 * 10] + ' ' + d1[num % 10] 

print(word(-100))
print(word(13))
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote if (0< = num <20 ) and again , if (20 <= num <100). And I wrote, if (num <0) above, if (0 < =num<20). and now I am getting traceback error (more recent call last) and recursion error(maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison)

Comment: Yes, the input is hardcoded and that is why I wrote - 100 and 13 in the print function. But I did not understand what you said about word[num].  Can you please clarify a little bit more? Now my code looks like this:                                                                                                                      def word(num):                                                                                                      ….   if  (num<0):        (and then (if (20 <= num<100)) ..